I need help filling in some in a step from Fomin's calculus of variations
At the bottom of page 20 from Fomin's book on Calculus of Variations, we have:
(1) $\frac{x+A}{c}= \ln( \frac{y + (y^2-c^2)^{1/2}}{c})$
Implies that
$y = c \cosh(\frac{x+a}{c})$
Can somebody help me fill in the steps?
My attempt: Exponentiating both sides of (1) gives us
$e^{ \frac{x+A}{c}} = \frac{y+(y^2-c^2)^{1/2}}{c}$
And I was thinking about multiplying by c, squaring both sides, trying to find some sort of quadratic like function in $y$ or something, but then figured that I was probably trying to hard and that one of the genius's that lingers on this site could help me out... thanks in advance!!
We prob need to use the fact that $e^x$ is the even part of $\cosh(x)$ i.e.
$\cosh(x) = \frac{e^x + e^{-x}}{2}$
Thx in advance!!

Let us isolate the essential part, write $X$ for the argument of $\cosh$, and $Y$ for $y/c$, and rewrite equivalently step by step:
$$
\begin{aligned}
Y &=\cosh X\ ,\\
Y &=\frac 12 (e^X+ e^{-X})\ ,\\
0 &= e^X - 2Y + e^{-X}\ ,\\
0 &= e^{2X} - 2Y\;e^X + 1\ ,\\
e^X &= Y \pm \sqrt {Y^2-1}\ ,\qquad\text{(Equation of second degree in $e^X$)}\\
X &= \ln(Y\pm \sqrt{Y^2-1})\ .
\\
X &= \pm \ln(Y + \sqrt{Y^2-1})\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
At the last step we use $(Y + \sqrt{Y^2-1})(Y - \sqrt{Y^2-1})=1$.
And the $\pm$ sign may be hidden in the constant $c$. (It escapes from the square root outside as $|c|$.)

thanks dawg!!!!!
